Event error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stopPropagation')
I can't use click modifiers when passing up the click event from a child component to the parent component. Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong here?
I have a component like this:
<!-- ButtonComponent -->
<template>
  <button @click="$emit('click')">Click Me</button>
</template>

<script setup>
</script>

And I'm using it like this:
<template>
  <ButtonComponent @click="doSomething()" />
</template>

When I try to apply the stop modifier, however:
<ButtonComponent @click.stop="doSomething()" />

I get the following error:

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stopPropagation')"

SandBox Example
Bonus: I'd rather not manually emit events from the child component. Instead, I'd rather the child component forward all events to the parent component.


The click handler is assigned to the root element due fallback attributes, so;

<button>Click Me</button> 


The error happens because .stop modifier actually assigns an extra handler that expects an object with stopPropagation method, pass the $event special variable, that will be handled by this extra handler:

<button @click="$emit('click', $event)">Click Me</button> 


Using the explicit $event is useful though with multiroot components:

VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
const $emit=defineEmits(['click']);
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="$emit('click', $event)">Click Me</button>
  <div>I'm a multiroot component</div>
</template>


Yes, why does it error tho?

@kissu added an explanation

@kissu added an example where $event is needed

Hm, I never had this bug because it was mostly implicit and worked well. But I guess that a few things changed with Vue3 and that it is now needed to have the $event declared explicitly. This could be considered a bug because I don't really see any benefit of making it explicit.

@kissu its not a bug, you forward an event without an event object. the error is from your side ‍♂️

I don't see why Vue's sugar syntax would forward a custom emit from a component implicitly but not one from an HTML element tbh. I mean, this situation would not happen often anyway, but I don't really see the benefit of crashing here, rather than being clever enough and forwarding the implicit $event. I'll maybe ask it one day on the core repo.

@kissu i don't see why Vue should add an extra parameter implicitly for a call that is written explicitly.

Because it does it already for the other cases mostly? Anyway. And I am not the OP + you're not supposed to ask the OP to accept or anything (puts pressure on people, apparently).

@kissu sorry, mistaken you for the OP...

Thanks! I'm so happy it was a simple solution.

It was at 2 votes and I upvoted and it still said 2 votes. I can't click upvote again either :shrug:
